# How to upload large file using AWS Gateway and S3 proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have AWS Gateway API configured as [proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) for S3 to upload a file to S3 bucket. I have configured binary media to support `multipart/form-data`

I am able to upload a file of size 10MB or less without any issue. However when the file size is more than 10MB i get `413 Request Entity Too Large` issue.

I know that AAG has hard limit of 10 MB on payload.

**Questions**
1>Isn't adding `multipart/form-data` should solve the 10 MB limit issue? Do i need to configure anything else?

2>Another approach recommended is to [create pre-signed url](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/uploading-large-payloads-through-api-gateway/). I am assuming for this approach to work client has to make call to get pre-signed url and then use that url to upload a file. Is this the only approach to upload a large file?

Note that I have gone through several SO post regarding the same issue, but most of them are old and i am curious to see if there are any new recommendations.

Comment: You should instead use multipart upload functionality provided by S3 and that solve this issue IMO. Checkout https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html for details.

Comment: I couldn't find any confirmation that you can use this API Gateway S3 Proxy feature for large, multi-part uploads beyond 10MB aggregate. You can definitely, however, upload directly to S3 via pre-signed URLs. And yes, your proposed approach in #2 is correct.

Comment: @Siddharth our clients are going to upload files. I am trying to avoid direct upload to S3 for our clients. In future if we change from S3 to something else then they have to change their code.

Answer (score 0):

The 10 MB payload limit is hard and cannot be increased [[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table)].

It seems to be possible to split the file into chunks on the client and then put it together on the server again [[2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=883356#jive-message-883500)] to circumvent the 10 MB limit, but I do not think this is a reasonable approach. The pre-signed URL approach seems better to me, if you do not use a client SDK which provides functionality for chunking.

Please note that if you ever decide to move away from S3, you can still implement the very same interface on any server yourself. In my opinion it is therefore the way to go.